# NetLogo : nw:save-matrix ordering of the nodes

Tags: r, social-networking, netlogo

I am generating different kinds of network in NetLogo 5.1 with the network extension.

I use *nw:save-matrix* to store the unweighted connectivity matrix of the network, that I then load into R to perform some more advanced computations.

**In this matrix, I'd like to know which line / column corresponds to which turtle.** I first though that the order will simply be the increasing order of the [who] (i.e. line / column 1 of the matrix would simply corresponds to the turtle with the lowest ID). Unfortunately, this does not seem to be the case.

I have tried different specifications for *nw:set-context*, aiming to sort the turtles in the network context. For instance:

> nw:set-context (turtle-set sort turtles)) (link-set sort links)
>
> nw:set-context (turtle-set map [turtle ?] (sort [who] of turtles))
> (link-set sort links)

I even explicitly specified each turtle by their [who] :

> nw:set-context (turtle-set (turtle 80) (turtle 117) (turtle 140) (turtle 153) ......

But these attempts were unsuccessful... I also noticed that the order is not random. For instance, I know that the node with the highest in-degree is turtle 80, but the matrix resulting from *nw:save-matrix* always corresponds to the 766th line / column.

Is it a matter of link ordering as well? Any idea about how *nw:save-matrix* actually works? Should I use another strategy to get this "ordered" connectivity matrix in R?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no consistent ordering. However, this was not intentional. I've created a bug for it: https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/151

As a workaround, you can actually generated the matrix files yourself pretty easily. Something like this will do it, though it includes all links and turtles, not just those in the context. Shouldn't be too hard to tweak if you're using a limited context:

```
to save-matrix [ filename ]
  if file-exists? filename [ file-delete filename ]
  file-open filename
  let turtle-list sort turtles
  foreach turtle-list [
    let source ?
    foreach turtle-list [
       let target ?
       ifelse [ link-neighbor? target ] of source [
         file-type "1 "
       ] [
         file-type "0 "
       ]
    ]
    file-print ""
  ]
  file-close
end
```

<s>I didn't have a chance to test this, but it should do the trick.</s>

Tested and updated with corrected code.

Comment: Thanks Bryan for this clarification and this very useful code!